# How to remove client id from url with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes

I'm creating urls like:

http://domain.com/app/**clientID**/controller/
or
../app/**clientID**/filename.ext

I need to remove alphanumeric clientID from the URL.

My current htacces is:

> RewriteRule ^app/([a-z0-9]+)*/(.*)$ /app/$2 [NC,L]

It passes the htaccess tester, but I get 404 error in the web.

Sample: http://domain.com/app/gmcpoujth7/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What does your error log in apache show? Look at it to know the real path it is trying to access when receiving an error 404

Comment: Is there a js file at app/js/fancybox/ named jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js? ...just asking to make sure

Comment: Yes the file exists.
Looked at the error logs.

File does not exist: /home/npxxx/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/clientID

Answer (score 0):

This is a two sided issue.

1. You want to remove the `clientID` from the url
2. You want the script to still work

In order for this to work you also need to add a rewrite script to tell your files where to access the files. This is a bit tricky and may require more work than just in `htaccess`.

Since the url are being rewritten and redirected you will need to have some way to redirect that url to the current `clientID`. This is the tricky part. You could add the following line to set a cookie:

```
RewriteRule ^app/([a-z0-9]+)/(.)$ /app/$2 [co=clientID:$1:.yourserver.com:7200:/,NC,L]
```

Then in the second call you would do a local rewrite like the following: *(Not Tested)*

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*clientID=([a-z0-9]+).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule /app/$ /app/$1/$2 [QSA]
```

This is not a full answer because if someone just goes to: http://domain.com/app/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js without first going to a url with the `clientID`, the server may not know where to send them if there is more than one `clientID`. Your best bet is to leave the `clientID` intact.

Comment: I think that it would be better to have sepperate URLs for all the clients. I just need to reroute files and controllers.

Comment: Like I stated, unless you have some other way of controlling the `clientID` it will be close to impossible. This could be a post/get variable, cookie, or other item. Without having someway to know what client is being accessed, there is no option but to leave it in there.

Comment: The problem is that all the clients are using the same core. So the controllers and the files need to be same for them with different urls on the addressbar.

Comment: Then why don't you pull the core files out of the client folders and host them in a different folder. Example: `http://domain.com/core/....`. Then you can redirect the url from `/app/clientID/..` to the `/core/...` for core files or have them directly link to them. But the problem still exists if you want to include the `clientID` for all files.